# Ansible: how handle servers on the same host?

Tags: ansible, development-environment, production-environment

I have been trying for days to setup Ansible to use it for getting up a dev environment for my project, and secondly deploy to beta and live servers. The project is not that big but it seems that Ansible is not flexible enough when it comes to small projects.

**Inventory**

```
[development]
web_server ansible_connection=docker
db_server  ansible_connection=docker

[production]
web_server ansible_host=10.10.10.10  ansible_user=tom  ansible_connection=ssh
db_server  ansible_host=10.10.10.10  ansible_user=tom  ansible_connection=ssh
```

I want to keep the `web_server` and `db_server` aliases intact so I can switch between development and production in my scripts without hustle. The main issue is that I can't figure out how to create a playbook that will work nicely with the above setup.

This solution doesn't work since it runs all tasks twice!

```
---
- hosts: staging
  tasks:
    - name: Setup web server
      command: uptime
      delegate_to: web_server
    - name: Setup db server
      command: ls
      delegate_to: db_server
```

This solution solves the above problem but it prints the wrong alias (`web_server` even when running the db task)!

```
---
- hosts: staging
  run_once: true
  tasks:
    - name: Setup web servers
      command: uptime
      delegate_to: web_server
    - name: Setup db servers
      command: ls
      delegate_to: db_server
```

This solution would be plausible but Ansible does not support access to an individual host from a group:

```
---
- hosts: staging:web_server
  tasks:
    - name: Deploy to web server
      command: uptime

---
- hosts: staging:db_server
  tasks:
    - name: Deploy to db server
      command: ls
```

Is there a way to accomplish what I want? Ansible feels quite restrictive until this point which is a bummer after all the praise I heard about it.

-------------------------- Edit after udondan's suggestion ----------------------

I tried udondan's suggestion and it seemed to work. However when I add a new group to the inventory it breaks.

```
[development]
web_server ansible_connection=docker
db_server  ansible_connection=docker

[staging]
web_server ansible_host=20.20.20.20  ansible_user=tom  ansible_connection=ssh
db_server  ansible_host=20.20.20.20  ansible_user=tom  ansible_connection=ssh

[production]
web_server ansible_host=10.10.10.10  ansible_user=tom  ansible_connection=ssh
db_server  ansible_host=10.10.10.10  ansible_user=tom  ansible_connection=ssh
```

In this case the IP of the staging server (20.20.20.20) will be used when running the production playbook.

Answer (score 2):

> This solution doesn't work since it runs all tasks twice!

Assuming that `hosts: staging` is what you have defined in `development` this is the expected behavior. You defined a group of hosts and by running tasks or roles against this group all hosts of that group will be processed. By delegating the task to a different host you only force the task to be executed elsewhere, but the task still is executed for each host of the group.

I think what you want is this:

```
---

- hosts: web_server
  tasks:
    - name: Setup web server
      command: uptime

- hosts: db_server
  tasks:
    - name: Setup db server
      command: ls
```

---

Update after response:

The problem is you use the same hostnames for all environments and try to delegate them to different connectors. What Ansible though is doing is this:

It reads your inventory from top to bottom, finds the groups and processes the groups in alphabetical order. (development, production, staging) It finds the host `web_server` in group `development`, so it creates that group, adds that host and sets the var `ansible_connection` for this host. It proceed to the group `production`, again finds the host `web_server` so it adds it to the group `production`, and sets the vars `ansible_host`, `ansible_user` and `ansible_connection`. But this is not specific for this group. It is set for the hostname `web_server`, overriding the previous value of `ansible_connection`. Ansible continues to the `staging` group and again override all the settings. The host `web_server` belongs to all 3 groups and its vars have been merged, even if you have targeted only one group, e.g. `ansible-playbook ... --limit=development`. The limit only limits the play to matching hosts, but the host still belongs to all groups and has all the (merged) vars which have been defined.

It is highly recommended and best practice to have an inventory file per environment. Not specifically for the problem you are facing, but simply to add another layer of security to not accidentally do anything to your production hosts when you actually want to target staging boxes. But it will also solve your problem. So instead of one inventory file like you'd have:

`inventory/development`:

```
[development]
web_server
db_server

[development:vars]
ansible_connection=docker
```

`inventory/staging`:

```
[staging]
web_server
db_server

[staging:vars]
ansible_host=20.20.20.20
ansible_user=tom
ansible_connection=ssh
```

`inventory/production`:

```
[production]
web_server
db_server

[production:vars]
ansible_host=10.10.10.10
ansible_user=tom
ansible_connection=ssh
```

Then you'd call Ansible with the appropriate inventory file:

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory/staging ... playbook.yml
```

If you somehow can not do that and need a single inventory file you need to make sure the host names are unique so the connection details are not overridden.

Comment: That seems to solve the issue! However I wonder.. how does Ansible know which `web_server` and `db_server` alias to use? Does it associate `group name == file name`?

Comment: After playing around with this, it doesn't actually solve the issue. If I add a staging group with the same alias names but different IPs, the production machines are being used instead of the staging ones!

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering if this is actually going to work this way... but I was not sure because you did not show how you exactly use your inventory. I updated my answer.

Comment: thanks for the update! What annoys me with this approach is that I have to create three separate files just for a total of 6 lines of configuration which is exactly what I was trying to avoid; unnecessary clutter. Thanks anyhow